# Standard Error of a formula

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, treatment

If I do have 100 samples of irrigated plants (labeled from 1 to 100)

and 100 samples of non-irrigated plants (during 5 days) (labeled to 101 to 200) from a **drought tolerant specie**

and

100 samples of irrigated plants (labeled from 201 to 300)

and 100 samples of non-irrigated plants (during 5 days) (labeled to 301 to 400) from a **drought NON-tolerant specie.**

I want to calculate biomass reduction which is a formula between weights of irrigated and non-irrigated plants.

SITUATION 1

How should I calculate the formula to get also a SE value? --> Plant nº1 irrigated with plant nº101 non-irrigated.

In this case plants compared are not the same plant.

Then do the mean and calculate the SE? = desvest(biomass reduction)/raiz(100)

SITUATION 2

Calculate biomass reduction using the mean of the irrigated vs each non irrigated

In this case is a comparison between a group and each individual

Then do the mean and calculate the SE? = desvest(biomass reduction)/raiz(100)

Many thanks

Comment: You have two samples A and B, and you want to estimate the SE of... the difference of means between the two samples?

Comment: I do have two groups of 100 individual samples (A & B). I wanna estimate the SE of biomass formula (%). BIOMASS REDUCTION PLANT = ((DRY WEIGHT OF IRRIGATED PLANTS/ DRY WEIGHT OF NON-IRRIGATED PLANTS)/DRY WEIGHT OF IRRIGATED PLANTS) *100   . So I wanna know how can I calculated the SE . Comparing irrigated plant 1 with no-irrigated plant I, 2 with 2, 3 with 3, etc.....  ... OR HOW?

Comment: I don't really understand, but it looks like you are estimating a proportion, is that correct? You should edit your question and add more details about your data, some examples, what it looks like.